# making click events with a loop jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, click

i am trying to make a slideshow that counts the amount of images inside a div. and makes a clickable circle for each image.

this is the code that seems to fail:

```
l = heroimgs.length;
for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
    $('#heronavpoint'+i).click(function(){
        $('.heroimg:visible').fadeOut(800);
        $('.heroimg:eq('+i+')').stop().delay(800).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, using a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        $('#heronavpoint' + i).click(function () {
            $('.heroimg:visible').fadeOut(800);
            $('.heroimg:eq(' + i + ')').stop().delay(800).fadeIn();
        });
    }(i));
}
```

In your case, you could use that:

```
$('[id^=heronavpoint]').click(function () {
    $('.heroimg:visible').fadeOut(800);
    $('.heroimg:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').stop().delay(800).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thx! no idea what is so different other than you using an extra function with a parameter?